# VitePress Unknown file extension ".css" for C:\Users\woo-m\Desktop\ToTimeMail\node_modules\vant\es\style\base.css

Tags: vue.js, vitepress

I have a problem in VitePress, I used VantUI, but he throws an error.

```
Unknown file extension ".css" for C:\Users\woo-m\Desktop\ToTimeMail\node_modules\vant\es\style\base.css
```

I found the file he mentioned, which is a Less, but VitePress should have built-in support for Less, and should not throw an error.

[image]

I also used elementPlus in vitepess, which is fully usable, but when I checked his source code, he did not use less, which may be the reason. But I don't know how to deal with him.

Comment: [Posts on Stack Overflow have to be in English](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/13676). Bilingual posts are not allowed, so I've removed the Chinese translation of your post.